# Rails + Filepicker - how to create a thumbnail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using Filepicker for upload and it's working quite well. Now I would need to extend functionality about creating thumbnails.

I am not really sure how it's working exactly, but when I upload an image, I get an URL (for example [https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WenvMkJjRpOeE6RIw3Vo](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WenvMkJjRpOeE6RIw3Vo%20-%20the%20original%20size%20https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WenvMkJjRpOeE6RIw3Vo/convert?w=650)).

When I add some parameters to this URL, like https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WenvMkJjRpOeE6RIw3Vo/convert?w=650, the displayed image is resized.

But how to set up resizing of an image while upload? I am familiar with Paperclip, where I set dimensions of all thumbnails and everything is created within the upload.

How it works with FilePicker?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the documentation?https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#inkblob-images

Comment: Yes, I did. but how to do that with Rails? That's the problem...

Comment: And another thing - how to save this image after resizing? (sorry, new with FilePicker)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly that you want to resize the image before you upload it to filepicker then

you can use the gem like [fastimage_resize](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage_resize) to resize your picture to push it to filepicker.

P/S: I doubt filepicker also uses the same mechanism to resize the image on the fly.

Comment: Well, my goal is to upload an image and from this image create 2 thumbnails with the respective dimensions. The problem is, that at the moment I am able only upload a file with using FilePicker.